# how do i display the table for a 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, console

I need to fill an array and display that array to the console (in table format).

Here is what I have so far:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        //Declare variables, strings and constants.

        const int ROWS = 10;
        const int COLS = 5;
        const int MIN = 1;
        const int MAX = 100;
        int total = 0;

        int[,] numbers = new int[ROWS, COLS];
        Random rand = new Random();

        //Populate the array

        for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < COLS; ++c)
            {
                numbers[r, c] = rand.Next(MIN, MAX + 1);                    
            }
        }

        //Display the array to console (table format)

        for (int r = 0; r < numbers.GetLength(0); ++r)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < numbers.GetLength(1); ++c)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,6} ", numbers[r, c]);
                if (c % 5 == 0) Console.WriteLine();

            }
        }
```

When i do this, my display if off by 1 and doesn't align properly for a 10x5 table.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the column index plus one, `c + 1`, is equal to the given column count, `COLS`, then write a new line:

```
if (c + 1 == COLS) Console.WriteLine();
```

Another way is to print a new line after all columns are printed:

```
for (int r = 0; r < numbers.GetLength(0); ++r)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < numbers.GetLength(1); ++c)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,6} ", numbers[r, c]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of your next line:

```
if (c%5 == 0) Console.WriteLine();
```

Notice that the first output, r=0, c=0, so it prints a new line